# VLAN support for Intel Desktop MT1000?

Tags: windows, vlan, intel

I have set up a VLAN DHCP server using Linux which works fine without a VLAN so now I'm trying to create VLAN then tagging to my windows client VM(Windows 10).

I have an Education version of Windows 10 using Intel Desktop MT1000 interface on VirtualBox.

**What I have tried:**

- Realtek Diagnostic tool but no VLANs appeared on that.
- Tried to download the driver for the Intel even though DesktopMT1000 
  was listed on the list.

This is what I'm getting?

[Can't find adapters even though one adapter is there?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIzzZ.png)

Can any help me out with VLAN support?

Comment: Assuming the MT1000 is the vNIC, you require VLAN support on the physical NIC. You should try to map a physical VLAN to another vNIC and use that (not sure about VirtualBox though). Realtek tools generally can't work with an Intel NIC and Intel tools won't work with a virtual NIC either.

Answer (score 1):

No support from Intel, change your NIC please.

> Intel® Ethernet Adapters supports configuring VLANs in any version of
>   Windows where full software support is available for that adapter.
>
> Based on your operating system, see if your adapter has full support.
>
> Intel® PRO/100 and PRO/1000 adapters that plug into PCI* or PCI-X*
>   slots do not support Intel ANS VLANs in any version of Windows* after
>   Windows Vista* and Windows Server 2008*. After these versions, only
>   the Windows inbox driver from Microsoft is available.

Comment: Is there any solution to how to solve this? I'm using an internal adapter the adapter types are only giving me little choices

Comment: @ThomasJH you will have to change the adapter sadly